# Parallax Image is very blurry

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I'm trying to use a parallx image on my site and I like the postion and placement of the image but the image is extremely blurry and I can't figure the css out to make it not so blurry. Here's what I have

```css
.Parallax {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/426/410');
  height: 300px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parallax"></div>
```

Comment: Please add enough code to your question to make the problem reproducable.

Comment: what size is the image you're using, I think the image will be too small

Comment: It looks like an image of 378x363

Comment: Try a higher res image https://picsum.photos/1920/1080

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing Parallax using the `background-size: cover` you need to make sure your image its high resolution unless you plan to use that image in a very small div which based on the image you are using it should be `width: 426px`

```
.Parallax {
  background-image: url('https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Great-barrier-reef-backgrounds-travel-gallery.jpg');
  height: 300px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

`

```
<div class="Parallax"></div>
```

Here is an example of your code but with a different image: https://jsfiddle.net/umq9cphf/